# Build and Analyze tool Cocoa Xcode

Tags: cocoa, xcode, memory-management

I tried Build and Analyze tool of Xcode very first time today.
and found some thing in this function

Please check the image:

[image]

```
-(IBAction)completeSessionButAct:(id)sender{
    NSDictionary *tempDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[self view],@"mainview",
                             congratulationScreen,@"screen",
                             congScreenLabel,@"cong_screen_label",
                             congScrStatusLabel,@"cong_scr_status_label",
                             [sender superview],@"last_screen",nil];
    [functionality completeSession:tempDic];
}
```

this function start from line 64 and end at 71

Can Any one explain me the memory leakage in this function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text as displayed in the image seems pretty clear to me: You are creating an object that you own (new, alloc, copy, retain [NARC] does that); but you never rescind ownership.

Try using `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` instead.

Comment: Or use -autorelease before your tempDict goes out of scope.

Comment: Obligatory documentation link: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi: Or just `-release`

Comment: True. I was in a rush and thought he was returning the dict. In that case it autorelease would've been perfect. Unless I'm creating many dicts at once, I tend to use [[[Class alloc] init] autorelease].

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/54tzB.png


in this code 
if I am using [records addObject:data]; in place of [records addObject:[data mutableCopy]]; then all objects in records array will be same value

and If I am using release in stead of removeallobjects than application crashes

Comment: Full Code Image - http://i.imgur.com/0WsRd.png,

Build and Analyze Image - http://i.imgur.com/54tzB.png

Comment: @Williham Totland - I use [tempDict release]; it solved , but now the problem I facing crashes in release as well as in autorelease

Comment: @Amit Battan: You want [[data mutableCopy] autorelease];

Comment: @Amit Battan: And no, you don't need to release the defaultManager